# Fields and quotient ring

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Let $P(X)\in{\mathbb{R}[X]}$ irreducible polynomial.

Then $\mathbb{R}[X]/(P(X)=X^2+1)\approx{\mathbb{C}}$. 
If  $P(X)=X^2+X+1$ also $\mathbb{R}[X]/(P(X))\approx{\mathbb{C}}$?

Or for a arbitrary polynomial (irreducible).

Thanks.

Comment: What is the degree of any polynomial surviving in $\mathbb{R}[X]/(P(X))$?  Is there an obvious thing that you can treat as the isomorphic image of $\mathrm{i} \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes, and "...or for an arbitrary **quadratic** irreducible pol. "